# Pandas - Return key from a column that looks like a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, string, types, split

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like this

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| data | {"foo":"bar","cat":"dog"} |
| data1 | {"foo":"car","cat":"log"} |

I don't think that the data in column B is actually a dictionary, but it looks like one. I'm trying to create a new column, C, with the value for "cat" for each row, so my desired output would be the same table as above, with a new column C appended to the end, like this

| C |
| --- |
| dog |
| log |

I've tried the following:

- snapshotT = df['B'].str.split(':')  --> this doesn't seem to do anything
- snapshotT = df['B'].rsplit(':',1) --> this one returns an error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
- snapshotTitle = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x.get('cat')) --> this one returns an error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

I understand that my general issue is that i'm trying to use attributes that don't work with my data type, but am not sure what else to try. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the string to standard python dictionary and then use `dict.get` to get the value:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df["C"] = df["B"].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x).get("cat"))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       A                          B    C
0   data  {"foo":"bar","cat":"dog"}  dog
1  data1  {"foo":"car","cat":"log"}  log
```